# Данные из Activity в Fragment

Tags: activity, android, android-fragment

Доброго времени суток. В моем приложении есть ActionBarActivity Tabs, эти табы заставили меня разбить работающее приложение на фрагменты, после чего оно стало неработающим. Вопрос: как из Activity > AsyncTask передать переменную result во Fragment1 > TextView1. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так же, как и всегда при работе с фрагментами, передавайте значение с Bundle:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String result) {
    CustomFragment fragment = new CustomFragment();
    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
    arg.putString(ARG_RESULT, result);
    fragment.setArguments(arg);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_RESULT)){
        mResult = getArguments().getString(ARG_POSITION);
    }
}
```

и когда нужен фрагмент

```
    mContext.getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, CustomFragment.newInstance("result text"), TAG_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
```

Возможны вариации, но мне нравится создание фрагментов оборачивать в статические методы, проверьте код на опечатки, писал тут, без idea.